# Rails + Carrierwave + RS Cloudfiles, how can I use multiple containers for one app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

I am developing an app that utilizes two different uploaders. What I am trying to do is to assign each uploader to different cloudfiles containers. I seem to unable to find any documentation about this, could anyone please help? Thanks!!

Comment: A couple of untested thoughts, but each Uploader carries it's own copy of the CW config settings so maybe you can override the Fog settings on each one. The CW group on Google is pretty active so you may want to ask there. The only other hurdle I see is getting Rails to respond with the correct asset host when you go to retrieve the image. You may need to setup an additional Proc to figure out what container a given uploader comes from. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

Carrierwave Wiki provide answer to this: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Define-different-storage-configuration-for-each-Uploader.

Basically you have to override the `initialize` method to set the configuration.